# Простое или составное сказуемое?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

В этом предложение глагол простой или составной? Нужна или нет запятая после "жду"?

**Жду когда меня откроют и наполнят.**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, так как союз *когда* открывает придаточное предложение. Не очень ясно, что вы имеете в виду под «простым» и «составным» глаголами, однако можно точно сказать, что никаких сложных глагольных форм в предложении нет. Все сказуемые простые.

> Жду, когда меня откроют и наполнят.